# C Makefile - missing seperator. stop

Tags: c, makefile

This is my Makefile, I get an error "***missing seperator. stop"
I am trying to compile a library but for some reason I get this error message. Other SO questions that are similar suggest that it is a tabbing issue, but i could not solve it.

```
CC=g++
RANLIB=ranlib

LIBSRC=osm.c 
LIBOBJ=$(LIBSRC:.c=.o)

INCS=-I.
CFLAGS = -Wall -g $(INCS)
LOADLIBES = -L./ 

OSMLIB = libosm.a
TARGETS = $(OSMLIB)

TAR=tar
TARFLAGS=-cvf
TARNAME=ex1.tar
TARSRCS=$(LIBSRC) Makefile README

all: $(TARGETS) 

$(TARGETS): $(LIBOBJ)
$(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ $^ //this line fails with the warning
$(RANLIB) $@

clean:
$(RM) $(TARGETS) $(OSMLIB) $(OBJ) $(LIBOBJ) *~ *core

depend:
makedepend -- $(CFLAGS) -- $(SRC) $(LIBSRC)

tar:
$(TAR) $(TARFLAGS) $(TARNAME) $(TARSRCS)
```

Comment: Tabs are mandatory at the start of the command line

Comment: Which lines here require tabs?

Answer (score 8):

Makefile requires that all "commands" in a rule are indented by one tab.

You have, for example, this rule:

```
clean:
$(RM) $(TARGETS) $(OSMLIB) $(OBJ) $(LIBOBJ) *~ *core
```

That is wrong, the command-line should be intended with an actual tab (not spaces) like

```
clean:
    $(RM) $(TARGETS) $(OSMLIB) $(OBJ) $(LIBOBJ) *~ *core
```

Comment: Thanks, why do I get the error in the specific line that I commented in the Makefile?

Comment: @Sharonica Because it is the *first* with the error. If you fix it, but not the others, then you will get an error on the next, and so on.

Comment: Apparently the problem was CLion's indentations as spaces. This should really be dealt with already.

Comment: Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 2):

```
CC=g++
RANLIB=ranlib

LIBSRC=osm.c 
LIBOBJ=$(LIBSRC:.c=.o)

INCS=-I.
CFLAGS = -Wall -g $(INCS)
LOADLIBES = -L./ 

OSMLIB = libosm.a
TARGETS = $(OSMLIB)

TAR=tar
TARFLAGS=-cvf
TARNAME=ex1.tar
TARSRCS=$(LIBSRC) Makefile README

all: $(TARGETS) 

$(TARGETS): $(LIBOBJ)
     $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ $^ //this line fails with the warning
     $(RANLIB) $@

clean:
     $(RM) $(TARGETS) $(OSMLIB) $(OBJ) $(LIBOBJ) *~ *core

depend:
     makedepend -- $(CFLAGS) -- $(SRC) $(LIBSRC)

tar:
     $(TAR) $(TARFLAGS) $(TARNAME) $(TARSRCS)
```

Answer (score 0):

make files have a specific structure and syntax. Generally:

```
<target> : <dependencies>
<tab><instructions>
```

The tab at the start of the line is part of the syntax.